# Сводная выборка из MySQL

Tags: mysql, выборка

Существует таблица MYSQL, которая имеет следующую структуру:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
    `ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `objectID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `actionID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `year` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `ID` (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Со следующим содержимым:

```
ID    objectID    actionID    year
 1       1           1        2013
 2       2           3        2013
 3       1           7        2014
 4       2           3        2014
 5       1           4        2015
 6       2           2        2015
```

Я делаю запрос следующего вида:

```
SELECT
    objectID,
    CASE year WHEN "2010" THEN actionID ELSE 0 END as "2013",
    CASE year WHEN "2011" THEN actionID ELSE 0 END as "2014",
    CASE year WHEN "2012" THEN actionID ELSE 0 END as "2015"
FROM data
```

И получаю следующий ответ (возможны несколько различных `actionID` для `objectID` в одном году):

```
     objectID    2013    2014    2015
         1         1
         1                 7
         1                 8
         1                         2
         2         3
         2                 3
         2                         2
```

Вопрос заключается в том, смогу ли я и каким образом, при некой модификации запроса, получить ответ вида:

```
     objectID    2013    2014    2015
         1         1      7,8      2
         2         3       3       2
```

Или:

```
    objectID    2013    2014    2014    2015
         1         1      7       8       2
         2         3      3               2
```

При использовании `GROUP BY objectID` отображается только одна из строк на ряд:

```
     objectID    2013    2014    2015
         1         1
         2         3
```

**Решение**, устроившее меня, на основе совета [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike):

```
SELECT
    objectID,
    group_concat(
        DISTINCT CASE years WHEN "2013" THEN km_typeID END SEPARATOR '; '
    ) as "2013",
    group_concat(
        DISTINCT CASE years WHEN "2014" THEN km_typeID END SEPARATOR '; '
    ) as "2014",
    group_concat(
        DISTINCT CASE years WHEN "2015" THEN km_typeID END SEPARATOR '; '
    ) as "2015",
FROM data
GROUP BY objectID;
```

Comment: применяйте агрегирующие фукнции. `SUM(CASE year WHEN "2013" THEN actionID ELSE 0 END) as 2013` group by который вы пишите конечно то же нужен

Comment: `SUM()` сработает не так как нужно, если в одном году для одного объекта несколько действий. Они, логично, просто суммируются. Хотя, справедливости ради, об этом я не упомянул, сейчас подправлю

Comment: Вместо `sum()` используйте `group_concat()`

Comment: Благодарю вас за подсказку. Действительно, такое решение меня устроит. Буду теперь думать как это улучшить. Заодно как не плодить одинаковые строчки в запросе.